# Meaning of “enforce from” here

Tags: meaning

Here is a quote from Daniel Goleman's book [Emotional Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_Intelligence):

> "*Indeed, the first laws and proclamations of ethics—the Code of Hammurabi, the Ten Commandments of the Hebrews, the Edicts of Emperor Ashoka—can be read as attempts to harness, subdue, and domesticate emotional life. As Freud described in *Civilization and Its Discontents*, **society has had to enforce from without rules meant to subdue tides of emotional excess that surge too freely within***.

I can’t understand the overall meaning of this part:

> society has had to enforce from without rules meant to subdue tides of emotional excess that surge too freely within

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Society has had to enforce* (from where?) *from without* (to enforce what?) *rules* (which are) *meant to subdue tides of emotional excess **that** surge too freely within.*

Comment: So “without” here means outside, thank your for explaining this